# char array to integer array

Tags: c

I got a set of characters as input using `scanf` which is actually like this `"1854?156X"`.

(using `scanf("%c",&input[i])` , input is an array of 10 characters);

In further processing of code I want to multiply the `(first digit *10)` & `(second digit *9)` and so on.

So, while multiplying it is taking the ASCII value of `1` which is actually `(49 *10)`, instead of `(1*10)`.

```
input[i]*counter;
```

where `counter` is

```
int counter=10;
```

How can I convert the char array to integer array where the exact digit should be multiplied instead of ascii value of that character?

Comment: Not necessarily portable to all other character sets, but in ASCII, at least, you can use `c - '0'` to convert `c` to its integer equivalent, provided you've verified (by `isdigit()` or similar), that `c` is, in fact, a digit.

Comment: i have verified the inputs with Isdigit

Comment: The reason I mentioned verifying a characters digit-ness is your sample input included '?' and 'X', which are generally not considered digits... The point is that input validation is a good thing...

Answer (score 3):

If you know ahead of time that you value is ascii then simply subtract the value of '0' from it. E.g. `'9' - '0' = 9'`

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use atoi(). It spares you a lot of manual character checking.

```
int input_val = atoi(input);
int temp = input_val;

while(temp)
{
  int digit = temp % 10;
  temp /= 10;
}
```

This gives you each digit from right to left in "digit". You can construct your number using addition and multiplying by powers of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Take the ascii value and subtract 48.

That is `input[i] - '0'`

...or rather use [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/). It returns zero if it fails on conversion, so you don't need to bother with '?' and such characters in your array while you traverse it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtol` to convert these character strings into integral types.

It's superior to `atoi` because the failure modes are not ambiguous.